# How to remove whitespace in a sentence using remove command in C++?

Tags: c++, string, stl, trim, erase-remove-idiom

I get a file as input and I read the first line like this (quotes mark the begin and end, but are not in the file):

```
"      1,     2.0,     3.0,     4.0                         "
```

When I use the remove command like this:

```
    astring = line;
    cout << endl << "Before trim: " << line << endl;
    remove(astring.begin(), astring.end(), ' ');
    cout << endl << "After trim: " << astring << endl;
```

I got the output as:

```
1,2.0,3.0,4.02.0,    3.0,     4.0
```

I need the output as `1,2.0,3.0,4.0` only.  What is the problem here?

Comment: Looks like the tab character.

Answer (score 7):

`std::remove` just moves all of the non-removed elements forward in the sequence; you then need to truncate the underlying container, using `erase`:

```
s.erase(std::remove(s.begin(), s.end(), ' '), s.end());
```

This is called the **erase-remove idiom**.  `remove` cannot truncate the underlying container itself because it doesn't have a reference to the container; it only has iterators to elements in the container.

Comment: I have to say, this is one of the weirdest things about the C++ standard library containers.

Comment: @Greg:  Yeah, the name `remove` is not really intuitive.  One way to look at it though is that operations on the elements in a container are generally non-member algorithms, but operations on containers themselves are generally member functions on the container classes.

Answer (score 0):

James was correct in his answer and it saved me a lot of work.
td::remove just moves all of the non-removed elements forward in the sequence; you then need to truncate the underlying container, using erase:

std.erase(std::remove(s.begin(), s.end(), ' '), s.end());
This is called the erase-remove idiom. remove cannot truncate the underlying container itself because it doesn't have a reference to the container; it only has iterators to elements in the container.